# looking for data source: all businesses in USA

Tags: data-request, usa, business

I'm looking for a source where I can download all business telephone listings (yellow pages) in the USA. Does anyone know where I might find such a data set?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to get historical listings also.

**Update/Clarification** I'm really looking for business names & geographic location. Telephone directories seem like a convenient place to get this information, but I don't actually need phone numbers. Any data set that contains business names and addresses (really just ZIP code would be enough) would be sufficient.

Comment: Short answer - sorry, you are not going to find this for free (I wish someone would prove me wrong!). [See also this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/free-database-or-api-of-all-north-american-businesses?rq=1). The only datasets I know of are proprietary (InfoUSA, Dun & Bradstreet, Nielsen Claritas, and Equifax B2B Marketing). Most states do have business records you can get (often for a price), but again you have to go state-by-state and compile it yourself.

Comment: i've come to a similar conclusion after quite a bit more searching. [This US Business database from Inbit](http://www.intbit.com/products/usbt/United_States_Business_Database.htm) the only one I've found remotely in my price range, though I have no idea what kind of quality it is. (They say up front they don't accuracy-check any of the data.)

Comment: You might not find a single source, but state Secretary of State offices tend to be responsible for business filings (incorporation/annual filings).  Those should be publicly available.  For states that don't have a "Secretary of State" or "Department of State", the responsibility tends to fall on the Lt. Governor.